Test Generator ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0
So I have built and trained a neural network that looks at xray data with 1177 unique classes. However, I would now like to test my model against the test/validation data but seem to be getting the following error when I use model.predict(test_generator):

raise ValueError( ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0


Please find my code here below:
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers, models
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import plot_model
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import data as tf_data
from tensorflow import image as tf_image
from tensorflow import io as tf_io

# Data augmentation
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
)

train_directory = r'/mnt/c/Users/dylan/my_xray_repo/train_test_split/train'
test_directory = r'/mnt/c/Users/dylan/my_xray_repo/train_test_split/val'


num_classes = len(os.listdir(r'/mnt/c/Users/dylan/my_xray_repo/train_test_split/train'))

# Prepare data generators
batch_size = 12
target_size = (224,224)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_directory,
                                              target_size=target_size, 
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              subset='training',
                                              class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(test_directory,
                            target_size=target_size, 
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            subset='validation',
                            class_mode='categorical')  

loaded_model = keras.saving.load_model(r'/mnt/c/Users/dylan/my_xray_repo/unet_x2_1.keras')

loaded_model.summary()

# 'model' is the trained model and 'val_generator' is the validation data generator
predictions = loaded_model.predict(test_generator)

import numpy as np

#Convert one-hot encoded labels to class labels for predictions
predicted_class_labels = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

# Convert probabilities to binary predictions
threshold = 0.5 
binary_predictions = (predictions > threshold).astype(int)

# Get true labels from the generator
true_labels = test_generator.labels

# Convert one-hot encoded labels to class labels
true_class_labels = np.argmax(true_labels, axis=1)

My first thought was to check if the test generator itself was producing data, which, according to this code I ran, it seems to be producing empty shapes and labels:
Code:
num_batches_to_display = 5  #  number of batches to display
for i in range(num_batches_to_display):
    batch_input, batch_labels = test_generator.next()
    
    # Print batch information
    print("Batch", i+1)
    print("Input shape:", batch_input.shape)
    print("Labels shape:", batch_labels.shape)

Output

Batch 1 Input shape: (0, 224, 224, 3) Labels shape: (0, 1177) Batch 2
Input shape: (0, 224, 224, 3) Labels shape: (0, 1177) Batch 3 Input
shape: (0, 224, 224, 3) Labels shape: (0, 1177) Batch 4 Input shape:
(0, 224, 224, 3) Labels shape: (0, 1177) Batch 5 Input shape: (0, 224,
224, 3) Labels shape: (0, 1177)

But I have also looked at the actual folder and it seems to have data in it:

The loaded model is one which I built and trained myself using a train_generator, and there were no issues. The test genertor should work as I just split the whole data into an 80/20 split. I am trying to find a solution to the current test_genertor issue, but to no avail. If someone could assist me with this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you

Hi, I have reviewed your code, and I noticed that the test generator is
showing zero elements. Please ensure that the test directory contains
subfolders for each class. Let me know if you are still facing the issues
